# What is the procedure to contact EASA to evaluate the certifiability of a system?

Tags: software, easa

I work in academia, and often we are "accused" of living in an ivory tower with no connections to the real world.

To reduce the gap between academia and this "real world" I've heard about, I would like to involve EASA in the research project I am currently involved in.

What is the correct procedure to do this?

For clarity:

- it would be only about software
- it is not something covered by DO-178C/equivalents (I have problems/questions about the high-level requirements, that are an input for the procedures in DO-178)
- it is a program running on a machine with a real-time operating system (RTOS) on board the aircraft. Currently we have no plans concerning maintenance cycles, so I would not be able to say if it could go on a easily exchangeable module (but my guess is no).

Comment: Are you trying to determine if it is certifiable, or is it similar to an already certified system? Are you looking to include software or complex hardware (FPGAs, PLDs)?

Comment: @selectstriker2 In theory I know it is not even remotely certifiable as of now, and I would like to work with them on how to make it certifiable. Software only. Note that this is not a DO-178 issue.

Comment: Are you looking at software embedded within a device/LRU or just the software program (such as one that would run in an RTOS)?

Comment: You say that it isn't covered by DO-178C, am I correct in assuming this doesn't actually go in/on the airplane?

Comment: @selectstriker2 (thanks for the questions!) currently I have no experience with LRUs, but from a brief look, I would guess it would not be compatible with such a strategy, so I have to say just the program, running on a machine with a RTOS. It goes in the airplane, but DO-178 covers the programming side, I have problems with the high level requirements.

Comment: This might sound stupid, but did you try their [official contact page](https://www.easa.europa.eu/contact-us)? There should be a process that will bring you into contact with the proper person on the other side. In the end, you will not deal with EASA but a specific representative who is responsible for your request. Worked well for me most of the time.

Comment: @PeterKämpf no, I did not yet try that, I first wanted to see if there was a specific channel available, but it seems to be the way to go for this specific situation.

Comment: Have you considered an industrial partnership with a company who are involved in the development of software for an aircraft application. They might be willing to partner with your university and talk you through the finer points. As selectstriker2 as already said, you can't get away from DO-178 if you are developing software for an airborne application but depending on the criticality of your application, not all of its objectives may apply to you.

Comment: @scotty3785 as I said previously my questions are not about development, DO178 does not apply to my questions. and no company would waste their time on something so untested.

Comment: @Federico then EASA are unlikely to speak to you either. They are incredibly busy and those in the industry have to book time with EASA reps months in advance. Perhaps you should ask your questions on here and those with appropriate experience might be able to help you. I'll keep an eye out for your question to see if I can help.

Comment: @scotty3785 I appreciate the intention, but aviation.se in not a scientifically citable source.

Comment: @Federico It isn't but if you actually ask the question, the best answers will come with references to citable sources.

Comment: @scotty3785 I don't know how to explain myself, I'll try one last time: the source can only be EASA, it is something never done before (or it would not be an academic project) hence there is nothing online or elsewhere that can answer me

Comment: @Federico Good luck in contacting EASA then.

Comment: @Federico, Is the software controlling any part of the aircraft or providing real time data to the flight crew, or is it more of a flight data collection and analysis software?

Comment: @selectstriker2 the first one you said (control over the aircraft). The thing is that I know how DO178 works, and I understand what are the procedure to follow it, but I need to know if my assumptions on the high level requirements are realistic or not.

Comment: @Federico, and what assumptions are those? Or are you referring to specific HLSW requirements for your project?

Comment: @selectstriker2 something that is specific to the project, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### DO-178 / ED-12C

Any software that executes on installed hardware in a type certified aircraft will need go to through DO-178C (or a similar process). The amount of effort involved depends on the safety criticality of the software functions.

Since this sounds like a new system without predefined System Requirements (such as those you would get from an OEM as part of the SAE ARP 4754A processes), those will need to be defined by your development process and then your Software (High Level) Requirements trace from those.

Here in the US, smaller companies will typically contact and work with the local ACO (Aircraft Certification Office) during the product planning stages to identify the product as following the DO-178C processes.

Larger companies, especially OEMs, tend to work with DERs (Designated Engineering Representatives) rather than directly with the ACO, as they may have dozens of different DO-178 projects going at one time.

### EASA Software Certification

Guidance on the EASA Software Aspects of Certification can be found in EASA CM -SWCEH - 002 [PDF](https://www.easa.europa.eu/system/files/dfu/certification-memoranda-import-EASA%20CM-SWCEH-002%20Issue%2001%20Rev%2001%20Software%20Aspects%20of%20Certification.pdf)

From that document, Panel 10 seems to be the part of EASA that you would work with, although I haven't found how a new applicant would go about contacting them yet.

> The EASA panel in charge of software and AEH aspects of certification.
>   This panel includes at least one software and AEH expert (who is the
>   coordinator) and, depending on the size of the project, may include
>   additional software and AEH experts.

There is also a FAQ page for the application processes with EASA:

https://www.easa.europa.eu/the-agency/faqs/application-process